# What is integral closure of $k [t^2, t^3]$ in $ k[t]? $

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

This question is from my assignment in commutative algebra.

> Question: What is integral closure of $k[t^2 ,t^3]$ in $k[t]$, where $k$ is a field.

Attempt: k is a field and hence k is UFD , hence k[t] is UFD.

If C is the asked integral closure, then $C=${$x\in k[t]$: x is integral over $k[t^2, t^3]$}

So, $x^n +a_1 x^{n-1} +...+a_n=0$ , all $a_i$ $\in k[t^2,t^3]$. Now, $x^n +a_1 x^{n-1} +... + a_{n-1} x^1 = -a_n $. Now, x divide RHS implies x must divide LHS , so $x=k_0 + k_1 t +...+ k_n t^n $ divides $a_n$ but I am not able to move forward from this.

Please help.

Comment: Hint. The ring extension $k[t^2,t^3]\subset k[t]$ is integral.

Comment: @user26857 Can you elaborate on this hint?

Comment: Sorry, what is $k[t^2,t^3]$? The subring of polynomials generated by $t^2$ and $t^3$?

Comment: @ChrisSanders Ya

Comment: $t$ is a root of $x^2-t^2$. The integral closure therefore includes the subring generated by $t$, but that is the entire ring.

Comment: I hope you're aware that if $a$ and $b$ are integral over $L$, then $a+b$ and $ab$ are also integral over $L$.

Comment: @ChrisSanders  Ya

Comment: Notice also that $k[t]$ is integrally closed, and it has the same field of fractions as $k[t^2,t^3]$

Comment: @ChrisSanders Kindly elaborate on your hint. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisSanders Can you please post an answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by OP:

Recall what you mean by the integral closure of $R$ in $S$.

This is the sub-ring containing every $s\in S$ such that $s$ is the root of a polynomial with all coefficients in $R$.

Now, let $R=k[t^2,t^3]$ and $S=k[t]$.

The polynomial $p(x)=x^2-t^2$ has $t$ as a root. Notice that $p(x)$ has all coefficients in $R$. See that $p(x)=1\cdot x^2+0\cdot x+(-t^2)\cdot1$?

Similarly, for any $j\in k$, the polynomial $x-j$ has $j$ as a root.

If you are given a sub-ring of $S$ containing both the whole $k$ and the element $t$, that sub-ring must be $S$ itself.

Comment: @Hi! Thank you very much for helping me. I have asked many questions in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry which haven't received any answers. I don't have any help in physical world as I am located in a very poorer part of the planet. I shall be really grateful to you.

Comment: So, the integral closure is $k[t^2,t^3]$ itself?

Comment: The integral closure of $k[t^2,t^3]$ in $k[t]$ is $k[t]$